# How to use `jsonb_set` on column with null values

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I am using Postgres 9.6 and I have a JSONB column in which some rows have `NULL` value and some have dict values like `{"notify": false}`.

I want to update the column values with more dictionary key/value pairs.

```
UPDATE accounts SET notifications =  jsonb_set(notifications, '{"alerts"}', 'false');
```

Does work for the cases where I already have values like `{"notify": false}`. The end result becomes as expected `{"alerts": false, "notifications": false}`.

But the value I'm trying to update us `NULL`, nothing is updated in the db.

Can you give me any ideas how I can update the `NULL` values as well, so the end result for them will be values like `{"notify": false}`. The end result becomes as expected `{"alerts": false}`

Comment: Did you try `jsonb_set(coalesce(notifications,'{}'), '{"alerts"}', 'false')`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET notifications =  jsonb_set(coalesce(notifications, '{}'), '{"alerts"}', 'false')
```

or even simpler:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET notifications =  coalesce(notifications, '{}') || '{"alerts": false}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that some versions of Postgres have coalesce() functions that don't support jsonb, and will give an error like this when trying to use the accepted answer:

```
ERROR:  function coalsece(jsonb, unknown) does not exist
```

You can work around that by using a case statement instead. Ugly, but it works.

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET notifications = 
  jsonb_set(
    case
      when notifications is null then '{}'
      else notifications
    end,
    '{"alerts"}','false')
```

Comment: *some versions* - in all supported versions (as of today 9.6+) `coalesce()` works well with `jsonb`.